# Detect Selected State of UIButton iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

How can I detect the selected state of a uibutton?

I have 7 buttons and I have made them to be able to toggle or select multiple buttons at a time.

I want to be able to tell which buttons are in a selected state when I push the done button.

So if M, T and W are selected then I want to be able to detect that when pushing done.

I currently put a tag on the button and then call a method to unselect or select multiple buttons.

```
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF = [[UITextField alloc]init];
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 32, 32);
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.delegate = self;
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"repeatWeekly"];
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeWP" size:15];
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.textColor = [UIColor appGreyText];
[self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:153/255.0 green:153/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.placeholder = @"1";
UIView *leftView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 12, self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.frame.size.height)];
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.leftView = leftView1;
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.keyboardToolbar = [self createInputToolbar];
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardToolbar;
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.delegate = self;
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.enabled = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF];

// Now, in your button action handler, you can do something like this:
- (void)mondayButtonTouch:(UIButton *)aButton withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
aButton.selected = !aButton.selected;

if(aButton.tag == 111) {

}

if(aButton.tag == 222) {

}

if(aButton.tag == 333) {

}

if(aButton.tag == 444) {

}

if(aButton.tag == 555) {

}

if(aButton.tag == 666) {

}

NSLog(@"dsfdfdfsdfs %ld", (long)aButton.tag);
[aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
```

Comment: using `NSMutableArray` to store `uibutton` tag and use this array for ur need

Comment: you can also use IBOutletCollection and when done button is pressed you can iterate thru the array and check what button is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `NS_ENUM` (which helps to keep a nice and readable code) and a `NSMutableArray` to keep track of your selected buttons.
Declare a enum that looks something like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Weekday) {
WeekdayMonday,
WeekdayTuesday,
WeekdayWednesday,
WeekdayThursday,
WeekdayFriday,
WeekdaySaturday,
WeekdaySunday
};
```

Then tag your buttons with the correct enum:

```
tuesdayButton.tag = WeekdayTuesday;
```

And check when you tap button if your enum exists in your array:

```
- (void)buttonTouch:(UIButton *)aButton withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if ([array containsObject:@(aButton.tag)]){ //exists, remove it from array
    [array removeObjectIdenticalTo:@(aButton.tag)];
    }
}else{
    [array addObject:@(aButton.tag)];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to create an `NSMutableArray` named `selectedButton`. Do like this:

```
- (void)mondayButtonTouch:(UIButton *)aButton withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    aButton.selected = !aButton.selected;

    if(!aButton.selected && selectedButton.containsObject(aButton.Tag)) {
        [selectedButton removeObject:aButton.tag];
    }
    else if(aButton.selected && !selectedButton.containsObject(aButton.Tag)) {
        [selectedButton addObject:aButton.tag];          
    }


    // do your stuff here
}
```

Now on `done` button click you have all the button thats tags are selected will be trackable with `selectedButton` array.

You can use:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:yourTagHere]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
for (UIButton *btn in [self.view subviews]) { // self.view (change it with your button superview)
    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && [btn isSelected] == YES) {
        // here you found the button which is selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[self.view viewWithTag:yourTagHere] replace